# Cannot create instance of type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I try to get my section from appsettings.json, and then bind it to the intance of MongoSettings class, but I have an exception which is:

> "Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing
>   a public parameterless constructor."

It is strange, because I'm using the same method to get jwt settings.

Please take a look:

```
    var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetSection("jwt").Get<JwtSettings>(); //it works
    var mongoSettings = Configuration.GetSection("mongo").Get<MongoSettings>(); //it doesn't
```

appsettings.json

```
  "Jwt": {
    "issuer" : "localhost:5000",
    "expiryMinutes" : 60,
    "key" : "das#@4SD120847@12313"
  },
  "Mongo": {
    "connection:" : "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "database" : "MemoTime"
  }
```

MongoSettings:

```
public class MongoSettings
{
    public string Connection { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
}
```

JwtSettings:

```
public class JwtSettings
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string ValidIssuer { get; set; }
    public int ExpiryMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, both clasess and sections in app settings looks similarly, so why getting settings for mongo does not work?

Comment: `"issuer" : "localhost:5000",` <---> `public string ValidIssuer { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Ou...you're right I missed it. But the rest properties are bound properly

Comment: `:` cannot exist anywhere in the key name.

Comment: Damn, what are the chances, I made the same stupid mistake :')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You Issue is in Json there is extra colon ":" that why it is giving error

> Valid Json Data.

```
"Jwt": 
  {
    "issuer": "localhost:5000",
    "expiryMinutes": 60,
    "key": "das#@4SD120847@12313"
  },
  "Mongo": 
  {
    "connection": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "database": "MemoTime"
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right. Now it works. How I could missed it...? Thanks :)

Comment: What kind of project is this? I tried .NET core console app and added `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` but error occurs: *'IConfigurationSection' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationSection' could be found*.

Comment: This asp.net core web application

Comment: Thanks. I found it to be an ASP.NET MVC project. An empty ASP.NET core web app still can not figure out the `Get<T>` method. This method is actually  declared  in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder` in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll`.

Comment: See Startup class in that project in that you can see ConfigureServices Method where we are going to write code for reading data from appsettings.json file

Comment: I was having an array for strings for my property value in json. These objects/array of string cannot be converted automatically into string type property in my C# class. Above answer helped to revisit my json property and C# class property.