# Azure Function Isolated Process .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have inherited a project that contains an Azure Function App. So far I have been unable to run this locally in VS Code. I have stripped the HostBuilder back to a bare minimum but when I call host.Run() I get the following exception

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it has multiple public parameterized constructors.'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, BindingPoint bindingPoint, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindProperty(PropertyInfo property, Object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindProperties(Object instance, IConfiguration configuration, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, BindingPoint bindingPoint, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.GrpcWorkerClientFactory..ctor(GrpcHostChannel outputChannel, IOptions`1 startupOptions)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

If I remove the 'ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()' call, then no error occurs. The documentation says that this function adds a whole bunch of stuff including default Grpc which I don't need.

I have searched high and low but I don't know why this error occurs. Can anyone help?

Regards
Alan

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create an Azure Function Isolated Process, the default code gets created with the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` method in
`Program.cs` file.

- `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` is used to configure the default Function worker Configurations.
- Iam able to run the App with the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` without any issues.
- As you mentioned, Even I have removed the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` call, Iam able to run the sample App even without the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()`.

[image]

- The error clearly says that there is an issue with the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()` with your code.

> this function adds a whole bunch of stuff including default Grpc which I don't need.

If you are not using any of the `code/calls/requests` related to `Grpc`, you can safely remove the `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults` and run the App.

- Your Configuration file has to be as shown below.

```cs
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Refer [Azure Functions Isolated Worker Environment](https://devkimchi.com/2021/08/13/azure-functions-openapi-on-net5/) by @devkimchi which explains configuration Isolated Function using `ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()`.

Check the similar issue in SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429397/cannot-create-instance-of-type-system-string-because-it-is-missing-a-public-p) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766409/cannot-create-instance-of-type-system-string), the cause of the issue can be the invalid format of the Configuration file.